# Visual Studio : ASP.Net MVC4 project publishing missing dlls

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Following dlls are missing while publishing a ASP.Net MVC 4 project.

```
System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll 
System.Web.Http.dll 
System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll
```

Any idea ?

Note :
Am publishing my files to a local path. There am not able to find these dlls in bin folder. And when hosted in an IIS, getting the error as dll is missing.

Comment: Missing from where? The output package?

Comment: Am publishing my files to a local path. There am not able to find these dlls in bin folder .

Comment: I assume you have "Copy Local" set to true for those assemblies. Can you try setting this to false, perform a Clean, then set it to true again and rebuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem. I used [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/) package for these missing library.

Type the following command into Tools > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client
```